# Java for NiTE/OpenNI 2/1.5?

Tags: kinect, openni

Have been scouring the web for the best java development setup for Kinect on Windows (and also preferrably Mac).

I thought the OpenNI/NiTE 2 was my solution, using Kinect drivers on windows and (until kinect drivers appear) the possibility (with the later MS SDK) to run a parallels virtual machine on a mac with the same setup. However, I discovered v2 of OpenNI/NiTE doesn't come with the java wrappers.

First, is there a java wrapper for OpenNI2/NiTE2 somewhere?

Secondly, I'm hoping to hear some experience

- is the difference between v2 and previous versions so big that I
  should suck it up and do my slower development in c++?
- is the tracking in general, near mode and sitting tracking, other dev tools,
  such a big advantage in the latest MS SDK, that I should consider
  using the MS SDK even though I don't care to be locked to windows for the future?

Comment: My experience is primarily in the MS SDK, so I can only address your last bullet point.  The "advantage" of the official SDK depends on your application needs and final destination -- cross platform applications are nice but they are not always necessary.  The MS SDK is very straight forward and does a very good job of tracking in both regular and near (aka: sitting) mode, but if your application doesn't require near mode there is no advantage there.  Though code differs, concepts are generally similar for SDKs -- you could start on MS SDK for now and move when/if the Java wrapper hits v2.